# how to create such effects with the help of photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-effects

i was searching some web styles on Google i found this style,(panel of a gift card)

[image]

i want to  know what style is this (every style have a name) and how to create this panel background with the help of Photoshop can anyone show me tutorials/how to's for this...

Thanks

Comment: No, not every style has a name, neither is there always a complete tutorial. What particular feature of the design are you having problems with?

Comment: i want to know background effect of the cards like there are lots of  lines and all this effects

Answer (score 4):

Looks like a standard design created by layering elements and setting blending or transparency on the layers. There are hundreds if not thousands of tutorials on these sort of text effects and drop shadows. If you've done nothing alone these lines, start with something like the tutorial below and go from there.

You can learn some of the basics though a [tutorial like this one](http://www.tutwow.com/photoshop/create-a-shiny-new-itunes-gift-card-in-photoshop/).

Comment: Besides that, the style does not really have a name i guess. I would list it under glossy

Comment: It reminds me of certain types of colored white glass based coffee cups.